# Could one theoretically create an arbitrary EM field inside a cavity by manipulating the potential at the boundary?

Tags: electromagnetism

There's a cavity (let's say a box for simplicity) and you have the ability so set the voltage of the boundary of the cavity at will over an extended period of time. Theoretically, would you be able to generate an arbitrary EM field inside?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by arbitrary.

For instance, one impossibility is that you cannot create an electromagnetic field that looks like you have an electron sitting inside the box. This is because of the $\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \rho/\epsilon_0$ Maxwell's equation. If there's no charge in the box, $\rho = 0$, then you find $\int_S \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{S} = 0$ for any closed surface within the box, which rules out the possibility of having an electron-like electric field.

Comment: But there's still a possibility of having an electric field if if flux contained in the box is zero and i would argue that with continuous change in boundary condition you can even set up an electromagnetic field

Comment: As the answer says, there’s no way with charge just outside a volume to create a field with del.E non-zero inside that volume. Doesn’t matter whether charges are moving or not, that would be inconsistent with Maxwells equations.

Answer (score 1):

A type of problems that falls within your criteria is the propagation of EM waves in a cavity. It is usually called transmission line or wave guide.
The mathematical analysis shows that, due to the boundary conditions, only a certain type of EM waves can propagate throughout the cavity. Controlling the boundaries allows to a certain extension to control the fields inside the cavity.

Ref:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveguide_(radio_frequency)
https://my.ece.msstate.edu/faculty/donohoe/ece3323waveguides.pdf